# UITextField becomeFirstResponder does not work

Tags: listview, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a listview on the bottom part of the screen and a 4 field entry form at the top part of the screen.  When I tap on the list item I would like to set focus to the 1st text field.

I have the code like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ....
    ....
    else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
        {
               [self clrscreen];

               [oDescription becomeFirstResponder];
            }
```

but it doesnt work.  Do I have to get the focus out of the listview first or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in the

```
[self clrscreen];
```

method you process the UI and the UITableView is redrawn. If that is so, at the moment you call the

```
[oDescription becomeFirstResponder];
```

it is not there. Please check if  `oDescription` is not `nil` .

One more thing: where/when is this called:

```
....
....
else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) ?
```

Comment: The clrscreen must have been the problem, I removed it and now all is good.  Also I added the header of the method I was in above.  thank you for the help!